# Registering Named services and resolving them by T

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, reflection, autofac

#### Problem statement

I have an application that needs to get files from various sources (disk, embedded, http, ftp, ...) so I use a common API for them:

> ```
> interface IResourceProvider { }
> ```

Then I just provide implementations:

> ```
> class PhysicalFileProvider : IResourceProvider { }
> class HttpProvider : IResourceProvider
> {
>   public HttpProvider(IClient client)
>   {
>       client.Dump();
>   }
> }
> ```

I register them as `Named` services:

> ```
> builder.RegisterType<PhysicalFileProvider>().Named<IResourceProvider>("App");
> builder.RegisterType<HttpProvider>().Named<IResourceProvider>("Remote");
> ```

I do this because I want to be able to replace them for testing so I need to know which service I'm replacing. Here, `PhysicalFileProvider` gets replaces by a *mock*.

> ```
> builder.RegisterType<PhysicalFileProviderMock>().Named<IResourceProvider>("Remote");
> ```

All these services are injected into the `CompositeProvider` which knows how to find a resource (usually by trying all of them).

> ```
> class CompositeProvider : IResourceProvider
> {
>   public CompositeProvider(IEnumerable<IResourceProvider> providers)
>   {
>   }
> }
> ```

This service should not know anything about the names so `IIndexed` isn't an option. It gets injected where required and it knows how to determine the correct provider.

#### Resolving `IResourceProvider`

In order to inject all `Named` services to the `CompositeProvider` I do some *magic*. I search for `KeyedService`s where their `ServiceType` is `IResourceProvider`. Then I group them by name and pick the last one as this one would be registered by the test as these registrations happen last just before I call `builder.Build()`.

```
builder.Register(context =>
{
    var services =
        from r in context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
        from s in r.Services.OfType<KeyedService>()
        where typeof(IResourceProvider).IsAssignableFrom(s.ServiceType)
        group (r, s) by s.ServiceKey into g
        let last = g.Last()
        select last.r.Activator.ActivateInstance(context, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>());

    return new CompositeProvider(services.Cast<IResourceProvider>());
});
```

#### Where's the catch?

Usually, you would register services with `As<T>` so that it flawlessly works with `IEnumerable<T>` but this *disables* `Named` and without additional filtering you would end up with three services injected into `CompositeProvider` These extensions seem to be mutually exclusive. That's what the manual `Register` and service search is for. It needs to pick the last `Named` service from a group of servcies with the same name.

#### Demo

In order to test this logic I create this demo code. Interface and class names are real. They just don't have bodies here.

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<PhysicalFileProvider>().Named<IResourceProvider>("App");
    builder.RegisterType<HttpProvider>().Named<IResourceProvider>("Remote");

    builder.RegisterType<WebClient>().As<IClient>();

    builder.Register(context =>
    {
        var services =
            from r in context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
            from s in r.Services.OfType<KeyedService>()
            where typeof(IResourceProvider).IsAssignableFrom(s.ServiceType)
            group (r, s) by s.ServiceKey into g
            let last = g.Last()
            select last.r.Activator.ActivateInstance(context, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>());

        return new CompositeProvider(services.Cast<IResourceProvider>());
    });

    // Override B for testing
    builder.RegisterType<PhysicalFileProviderMock>().Named<IResourceProvider>("Remote");

    var container = builder.Build();
    var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();

    scope.ResolveNamed<IResourceProvider>("App").Dump();
    scope.ResolveNamed<IResourceProvider>("Remote").Dump();
    scope.Resolve<CompositeProvider>().Dump();
    scope.Resolve<IClient>().Dump();
}


interface IResourceProvider { }

interface IClient { }
class WebClient : IClient { }

class PhysicalFileProvider : IResourceProvider { }
class HttpProvider : IResourceProvider
{
    public HttpProvider(IClient client)
    {
        client.Dump();
    }
}

class PhysicalFileProviderMock : IResourceProvider { }

class CompositeProvider : IResourceProvider
{
    public CompositeProvider(IEnumerable<IResourceProvider> providers)
    {
        providers.Dump();
    }
}
```

#### Questions

- Would you say this solution is sane?
- Is there a better one?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, doesn't the latest registration overwrite earlier ones? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754702/override-autofac-registration-with-plugin

Comment: @dfhwze yes and no; it does when you resolve `Remote` so you'll get the latest registration but you'll get all three when you manually search them o_O this is why I need the grouping and last.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make an extension method on _container_ that does this for you given any type _T_ ? I think _ComponentRegistry_ is available on the container as well.

Comment: @dfhwze mhmm... usually yes but this kind of _tricks_ are so rare that I actually wasn't going to reuse it anywhere else.

Comment: The unit test does not care about the name. How will you let it use the mock if _scope.Resolve<CompositeProvider>()_ returns the last registered value for each named key?

Comment: @dfhwze I'm not sure I understand the question... the last registered service for each key is the one that was registered by a unit-test and this one should be used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96054/discussion-between-dfhwze-and-t3chb0t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is sane, and it can easily be extended to a generic extension method. `Last()` is the best you can do. It would have been better if `context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations` somehow stored some registration meta info like `DateTime` of registration. There is a *meta* dictionary foreseen, but it is unclear what is stored inside.

```
public static class AutofacExtension
{
    public static void RegisterComposite<T, TComposite>(
        this ContainerBuilder builder) where TComposite : class
    {
        if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            var services =
                from r in context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
                from s in r.Services.OfType<KeyedService>()
                where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(s.ServiceType)
                group (r, s) by s.ServiceKey into g
                let last = g.Last()
                select last.r.Activator.ActivateInstance(
                    context, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>());

            return Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof(TComposite), services.Cast<IResourceProvider>());
        });
    }
}
```

And registered..

```
builder.RegisterComposite<IResourceProvider, CompositeProvider>();
```

Instead of..

> ```
> builder.Register(context =>
> {
>     var services =
>         from r in context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
>         from s in r.Services.OfType<KeyedService>()
>         where typeof(IResourceProvider).IsAssignableFrom(s.ServiceType)
>         group (r, s) by s.ServiceKey into g
>         let last = g.Last()
>         select last.r.Activator.ActivateInstance(context, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>());
>
>     return new CompositeProvider(services.Cast<IResourceProvider>());
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not into that whole brevity thing, so I like longer variable names, even for lambda expressions. Plus I like method chaining over query comprehension syntax. I'm weird like that. So the big wiring up block gets a little bigger .. definitely not better, but I wanted to just show an alternative for funsies.

```
builder.Register(context => new CompositeProvider(context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
    .SelectMany(
        registration => registration.Services.OfType<KeyedService>(),
        (registration, service) => (registration, service))
    .Where(registrationService => typeof(IResourceProvider).IsAssignableFrom(registrationService.service.ServiceType))
    .GroupBy(registrationService => registrationService.service.ServiceKey, registrationService => (registrationService.registration, registrationService.service))
    .Select(registrationService => (registrationService, Last: registrationService.Last()))
    .Select(registrationService => registrationService.Last.registration.Activator.ActivateInstance(context, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>()) as IResourceProvider)));
```

Comment: I think you lose readability when using long variable names in lambda expressions. Besides that, since we now have _ValueTuple_, I would also prefer that over an anonymous class, if used as a local intermediate class, again for readability.

Comment: `ValueTuple` - excellent call!